# I am trying to access variables inside one function into another function with both the functions in the same class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I have a function named `check_database` in which I have variable `$username`, I have created another function named `get_val()` in which I am trying to access `$username` variable in my `get_val()` method. Please let me know how to do it.

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }

function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }

function get_val()
{

$this->check_database();

}

 

 }
```

Comment: What if we make $username a class variable ?

Comment: Improved formatting, probably more needed

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting session in check_database method you can retrieve it via session.

```
$username= $this->session->all_userdata()['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a private variable username in class then assign the value post('username') in to it ... then access anywhere you wish.

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {
private $username;

function check_database($password){
$this->username = $this->input->post('username');
}

function get_val(){
echo $this->username;
}

}
```